# PHP make variable from body content.

Tags: php, html, email

Is there anyway to get make a variable equal the content of the body?

Example:

```
<?php 

//PHP

$body = { ?>

<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>


<?php } ?>
```

So that I can use it send a e-mail.

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, 'From: <$EmailFrom>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - use the output buffering functions:

```
ob_start();

// Echo your output here or

?>

<div>Just output your HTML like this</div>

<?php

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in PHP

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<? 

$body = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">"
$body .= "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"
$body .= "<head>"
$body .= "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"
$body .= "<title>Untitled Document</title>"
$body .= "</head>"
$body .= "<body>"
$body .= "</body>"
$body .= "</html>"

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check this way

<?php 

//PHP

$body = '

<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>';

 ?>
```

Comment: Dangerous - what happens if a `'` appears in the output?